# Processing headers with rsocket in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, rsocket, spring-rsocket

I am testing RSocket request-response logic and have some problem with processing headers.

I am using spring boot 2.7.9 with Kotlin.

My Controller:

```
package com.mol.rsocket.controller

import com.mol.rsocket.model.HelloRequest
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Headers
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import reactor.kotlin.core.publisher.toMono

@Controller
class Controller {

    @MessageMapping("hello")
    fun currentMarketData(
        request: HelloRequest,
        @Headers headers: Map<String, String>,
    ): Mono<String> {
        println("Headers ${headers.keys}")
        return "Hello ${request.name}!!".toMono()
    }
}
```

And my build.gradle

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.9"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
}

group = "com.mol"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-rsocket")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

For testing requests I use rsocket-cli and my request looks like:
`rsocket-cli --route=hello -i "{\"name\": \"Kirill\"}" --header foo:bar --header hello:world --request tcp://localhost:7000`

So in the console I don't see my headers keys. Only this:

Headers [dataBufferFactory, rsocketRequester, rsocketResponse, lookupDestination, contentType, rsocketFrameType]

I found some information about extracting headers here, but it doesn't helps me
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/rsocket.html